# How can (X|X>Y) change to (X-Y|X>Y)+(Y|X>Y)?

Tags: stochastic, exponential-distribution

If X~Exp(a), Y~Exp(b), consider (X|X>Y).
My book said that (X|X>Y)=(X-Y+Y|X>Y)=(X-Y|X>Y)+(Y|X>Y).
But Why?? I don't know why we can divide those two things.

Comment: this question doesn't belong here

Comment: Oh where should I post it??

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Overflow doesn't support MathJax/LaTeX to my knowledge so here is an image:

[image]